# Fitnesse smartrics.rest.fitnesse.fixture.RestFixture.setBaseUrl

Tags: rest, fitnesse

I have a requirement for a test to make a call to one REST endpoint that generates a security token then make a second to the actual system under test. In order to do this I am using smartrics.rest.fitnesse.fixture.RestFixture and setting the baseurl in instantiation to the first base. I am trying to make this call and then set the new baseurl to the new location but am having trouble doing so.

It appears from perusing the code that there is a method setBaseUrl(Url url) but I cannot find an example of using this and am failing trying to figure it out myself.

Has anyone had any luck with this or is there another, better/easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in RestFixture:processRow - since it uses Java reflection, it attempts to call method without parameters. This will fail since setBaseUrl accepts one argument (Url). I have tried one modification, though not the best way to achieve it - current code RestFixture v3.0 (RestFixture.processRow()):

```
method1 = getClass().getMethod(methodName);
method1.invoke(this);
```

Modified code in RestFixture.processRow():

```
Method[] methods = getClass().getMethods();

int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < methods.length; i++){
    if(methodName.equals(methods[i].getName())){
        method1 = methods[i];
        break;
    }
}

Class[] paramTypes = method1.getParameterTypes();

List<Object> params = new ArrayList<Object>();

for(i = 0; i < paramTypes.length; i++){
    String cellText = row.getCell(i+1).text();
    Object param = paramTypes[i].getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(cellText);
    params.add(param);
}

method1.invoke(this, params.toArray());
```

Once this modification is done (you might need to add required imports - java.lang.InstantiationException, java.lang.Object, java.util.ArrayList; and an exception handler for InstantiationException), re-build the RestFixture and that should work.

Answer (score 1):

We had what sounds like a similar requirement - we needed to use RestFixture(POST) to retrieve a URL for use in a subsequent RestFixture call(GET).
(Note that we're using an ancient RestFixture 1.1)

I modified the processArguments() method in RestFixture.java thus:

`// baseUrl = new Url(args[0]); // original line
baseUrl = new Url(resolve(args[0])); // modified`

With this modification in place, my Fitnesse test looks like this:

`!| RestFixture | http:///fds |
| setBody |{"param1":"blah","param2":"blather"} |
| POST | /GetThatUrl | 200 | | |
| let | **$urlresult** | body | |

!| RestFixture | **$urlresult** |
| GET| | 200 | Content-Length:[\d]+ | ||`

Without the code change, $urlresult was not resolved and I could not pass in the URL as a variable.